# How to read and use ajax array in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I don't know how to, or what to put in my PHP file to retrieve the array data that is sent by an AJAX request. What do I need in my PHP file to be able to isolate the array items one-by-one? (the amount of items in array will be dynamic)

I am getting checked checkboxes value, and putting those values into an array. I will be using this array to put them into a string. I have tried the following in my PHP file and haven't gotten any results...either results in an error, or the page echo's/responds with nothing.

```
foreach ($_POST['$inputBoxesValues'] as $value) {
  echo $value;
}
```

```
$amount = count($_POST);
for ($x = 0; $x <= $amount; $x++) {
  echo $_POST[$x];
}
echo implode(",", $_POST);
```

I've now tried this.. and php file responded with nothing
**new AJAX function**

```
function formProcess() {
  var inputBoxesValues = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map( function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(inputBoxesValues);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'itemprocessor.php',
    data: {data : jsonString},
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
      window.location.href = "compare.php?" + result;
    }
  });
  console.log(jsonString);
}
```

PHP file...

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
foreach($data as $d){
  echo $d;
}
```

I know to use, create, and edit strings in PHP, but I just don't know how to use the array data sent to the file.

This function is called when 'continue' button is pressed *(the following is the original code)*

```
function formProcess() {
  var $inputBoxesValues = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map( function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get(); //makes array
  $.ajax({
    url: 'itemprocessor.php',
    data: $inputBoxesValues,
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
      window.location.href = "compare.php?" + result;
    }
  });
  console.log($inputBoxesValues);
}
```

**Expected result/method for result**
- User selects boxes (which has values) and clicks continue,
- AJAX sends data containing an array of the values of the selected checkboxes,
- PHP file sends back a string, something like `item1,item2,item3`
- AJAX script then sends user to 'compare.php' page with the response string
- 'Compare' page uses the GET data in url

Currently am only up to the 2nd step, how to I achieve reading the AJAX data?

**Update:**
I have now tried other things, (listed above), but one thing I've noticed, is that in my php code, even if I try to do `echo "Foo Bar";`, the PHP code still returns nothing. But when I simply type no PHP code in the file and just type "`Foo Bar`", in normal text, no html formatting or anything. the file responds with "`Foo Bar`"
Noting this, I've now also tried to put `echo '<span>'. $d .'<span>';`. This then makes the file return "`'. $d .''; } ?>`". What the heck is going on?

Comment: Why not try some of the answers you already found? If none of them are working for you, update this question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `POST` you can use `$_POST` in your php page where ajax is send. You can use `$_POST['variable_name']` to get each data.

As in your case try `$_POST['$inputBoxesValues']` to get array and do a foreach to iterate through each values.

Comment: sorry dude, but I just don't understand foreach, I just can't seem to get it to work with my array? I think what I've done is correct?  
`
foreach ($_POST['$inputBoxesValues'] as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
`  
I get...  
`
Notice: Undefined index: $inputBoxesValues in F:\xampp\htdocs2\services\itemprocessor.php on line 10

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in F:\xampp\htdocs2\services\itemprocessor.php on line 10
`

Comment: If you tried something and you got some errors, add it to your question. This way more people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so.. basically I'm an idiot, but I now know for next time!
I had commented out the previous attempts, and the different methods I had used so I didn't 'start new' every time.

**The FULL PHP file I had**

```
<?php/*
    $amount = count($_POST);
    //echo $amount;
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $amount; $x++) {
      //  echo $_POST[$x];
    }
   // echo implode(",", $_POST);
    echo array($_POST);

    $nickname[] = $_POST;
    echo $_POST['webdesign'];*/

    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
    foreach($data as $d){
        echo $d;
    }
?>
```

The problem was the damn comment out thing (`/*`) at the top. It had no space and it wasn't on a new line, I didn't know that was a requirement.. To fix it, I put the comment characters on a new line

```
<?php
/*
....
```

**My final working code**
*jQuery/AJAX:*

```
function formProcess() {
    var inputBoxesValues = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map( function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'itemprocessor.php',
        data: {data : inputBoxesValues},
        dataType: 'text',
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(result) {
            window.location.href = "compare.php?options=" + result;
        }
    });
    console.log(inputBoxesValues);
}
```

*PHP:*

```
<?php
    echo implode(",", $_POST['data']);
?>
```